# combine submit and click function

Tags: jquery, forms, form-submit

I want to use the same function if the user submit the `#postcode-form` or click on `#show-results` link. How can I do it without duplicate the function?

**HTML**

```
<form id="postcode-form">
    <input id="postcode" type="text" name="postcode" />
    <input type="submit" value="search" />
</form>
<a id="show-results" href="#">Show the results</a>​
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$("#show-results").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        codeAddress(postcode);
});​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#postcode-form").submit(function(){
    //your submit function, validation, etc.
});

$("#show-results").click(function(e){
    $("#postcode-form").submit();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the link submit the form instead:

```
$('#show-results').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#postcode-form').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add onsubmit event on form forcefully stops form to submit and on click on submit-results link you can forcefully submit form either by ajax or simple form submit method.

```
<form id="postcode-form" onsubmit="return false;">
    <input id="postcode" type="text" name="postcode" />
    <input type="submit" value="search" />
</form>
<a id="show-results" href="#">Show the results</a>​
```

and the js

```
$('#show-results').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#postcode-form').submit();
    });
```

Comment: Yeah, you're right but I would rather not mix the markup with inline js code. Instead add an `event.preventDefault()` to the `submit` method's function body.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$('#show-results').submit();
```